# How to upload files - Sveltekit

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

+page.svelte

```
<form
    action="?/upload"
    method="post"
    enctype="multipart/form-data"
  >
<input
      type="file"
      name="file"
      id="file"
      accept="application/pdf"
    />
```

+page.server.js

```js
export const actions = {
  upload: async ({ cookies, request, locals }) => {
    const data = await request.formData();

    //HOW CAN I GET and save the file locally with writeFileSync?

    return { success: true };
  }
};
```

I haven't found a way to handle file uploads in sveltkit. Any ideas? The file is small.. so there is no problem in loading to memory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just get a [`File` instance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) from the form data and read it via one of its methods like `text()`, `stream()` or `arrayBuffer()`. e.g.

```js
// would recommend using these async functions
import { writeFile } from 'fs/promises';

//...

const file = data.get('file'); // value of 'name' attribute of input

await writeFile(`./files/${file.name}`, await file.text());
// or
await writeFile(`./files/${file.name}`, file.stream());
// or
await writeFile(`./files/${file.name}`, new Uint8Array(await file.arrayBuffer()));
```

Writing files is a fairly dangerous operation, would recommend validating that the file name is actually just a name, not a full path.

Comment: Thanks! That what I was looking for... do you know any link where I can learn more?

Comment: The file API is a web standard, the linked MDN documentation should explain its properties, methods and the various related classes. I just read through that or search StackOverflow if there is a specific use case that might be common enough.

Comment: typescript support: ```const file = data.get('file') as File; ```. Furthermore on the documentation, [File (constructor)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File)